# Disable iOS Screenshot/Splash

Tags: ios, codenameone

In the section "[The iOS Screenshot/Splash Screen Process](https://www.codenameone.com/manual/appendix-ios.html#section-ios-screenshots)" of the Codename One manual, it's written that it's possible to disable the screenshot process only on debug builds.

Suppose that I want to disable at all the splash screen functionality also on production builds: what does it happen if I replace all the ten iOS Device Screenshots with fully transparent pngs in the native/ios directory in my project?

At the moment, I haven't an iPhone, but only Android devices, so I cannot test what I've just suggested.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use an emulator?  If you ever plan on releasing your software you'll need to be able to test on one, so you would likely be better off getting one and trying it yourself.

Comment: Yes, there are two reasons: the first one is that Codename One simulator doesn't render the iPhone splashscreen; the second one is that I doesn't know any way to emulate an iPhone on Linux and an iPhone emulator cannot be run inside a VirtualBox machine. Of course, if you know a way to run an iPhone emulator inside a Linux machine, tell me :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable it without screenshots only for debug builds but if you provide ready made splash screens for all the resolutions/orientations in the `native/ios` directory the screenshot process shouldn't happen.

Comment: Thank you Shai, however my question is about what does it happen with fully transparent pngs.

Comment: You would have a problem, iOS relies on this showing actual content